# I'm unable to set 2560x1440 resolution on Intel HD 5000 using Displayport with PG278Q

Tags: resolution, intel, monitor, displayport

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm unable to get the monitor working.

Screen works fine in BIOS and the same machine when booting to windows (before installing Ubuntu).

I have tried the xrandr commands to add the resolution but the monitor just goes to out of range once set.

Connecting a different screen via HDMI works fine and at 1920x1080 with no messing.

Edit: All system updates loaded, I previously installed the Intel driver hoping that would fix issue.

Edit: Reinstalled, all system updates.

Machine: Intel NUC D54250WYB
Monitor: Asus PG278Q

As requested:

```
uname -r
3.13.0-43-generic

apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel | grep -F Installed
Installed: 2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.3

xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
1024x768       60.0* 
800x600        60.3     56.2  
848x480        60.0  
640x480        59.9  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I try and set the resolution as follows:

```
$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync

$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60" 312.25 2560 2752 3024 3488 1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

As soon as I enter the following I get an "out of range" message on monitor and have to connect a different one switch the resolution back.

```
$ xrandr --addmode DP1 2560x1440_60
```

Comment: Could you please provide the output of the following commands in your question ([edit] it)? `uname -r`, `apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel | grep -F Installed`, `xrandr --current` (while connected with the 2560x1440 monitor)

Comment: Linux `3.13.0-32-generic` is old, indicating you did not install system updates (should be `-43` at the time of writing). Same for the Intel driver which should be `2:2.99.910-0ubuntu1.3` at the time of writing. Please run all your system updates and reboot. Then report back. Oh, and does the screen work in the BIOS/POST before the boot sequence starts Ubuntu? (it should, if not, please include that in your post)

Comment: Reinstalled and updated original question with more detail.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: I have an identical problem as the OP. 
  Installed: 2:2.99.911-0intel1, 3.13.0-43-generic . Monitor works 2560x1440 @ 85hz on windows on the same machine. I have HD4000 and connect via displayport.